# iOS Custom Camera - Take Photo Instantly

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, avcapturephotooutput

In my app I created a custom camera view for image capturing.
When I trigger capturing, I use the following code:

```
private func takePhoto() {
   let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
   self.stillImageOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
}
```

This then triggers `photoOutput didFinishProcessingPhoto`

There I extract the `UIImage` from the `AVCapturePhoto` and carry on.

My problem is in between I call `self.stillImageOutput.capturePhoto` and the image arrives in `didFinishProcessingPhoto` an average 0.5 second passes and I would need the capture image (almost) exactly at the time `capturePhoto` was called.

Is there a way to speed this process up or is there another way how I can achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

`let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()` write outside of `takePhoto` function, when you call `takePhoto` function at that time create a new memory and allocate to `settings` variable, So If you define globally in this controller then memory will allocate when this controller load and it would speed up process to take photo.

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't do the magic.
Most likely this cannot be done as others suggested it too, but still, it worth the try.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, Once upon a time I have faced the same issue with an open camera and photo library (UIImagePickerController), I have defined a global variable in the controller to solve this issue. it works fine with speed up process.